# LINQ compare 2 tables, only return previous item, not all

Tags: c#, linq

So...Each workstation has a number of invoices, My Linq statement joins the workstation to the invoices and compares them all.
I only want my LINQ to select the most recent invoice (the previous invoice produced for that workstation).

ATM all invoices are compared and any invoices (for that workstation) that are <= 1 year ago today, will be returned.  I only want it to return if that previous invoice for each workstation is < 12 months of today.

With help from a previous Q, this is what I have atm...

```
   DateTime OneYearAgo = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);

        var SelectedObject =
            (from workstation in db.Work_Sites
             join invoice in db.Invoices on workstation.id equals invoice.Site_Id
              where invoice.Invoice_Date <= OneYearAgo
             select workstation).Distinct().ToList();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  DateTime OneYearAgo = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);

  var SelectedObject =
            (from workstation in db.Work_Sites
             join invoice in db.Invoices.Where(i => i.Invoice_Date <= OneYearAgo)
                   on workstation.id equals invoice.Site_Id into g
             where g.Any()
             select workstation).ToList();
```

This will return workstations which have at least one invoice year ago.